# One HTML form text box doesn't show keyboard input in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a form in my HTML that takes in first name, last name, and phone number to create an account ID. The input textboxes for first name, last name, and account ID accept keyboard input and display it, as would be expected. However, when I'm viewing the page on the Firefox browser, only the phone number textbox doesn't work. I can click into the box once and see the cursor, but as soon as I start typing, no text shows up, and the cursor disappears. However, based on the Javascript creating an account ID with the last four digits of the phone number typed, I know the input is recognized. It works in other browsers, just not in Firefox.

```
        <article>
            <h2>New Account Information</h2>
            <form>
                <fieldset id="deliveryinfo">
                    <label for="fnameinputacct">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="fnameinputacct" name="fname" />
                    <label for="lnameinputacct">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="lnameinputacct" name="lname" />
                    <label for="phoneinputacct">Phone Number</label>
                    <input type="text" id="phoneinputacct" name="phone" />
                    <label for="accountidbox">Account ID</label>
                    <input type="text" id="accountidbox" name="accountid" />
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="submitbutton">
                    <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Create Account" />
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </article>
```

Here is the CSS

```
fieldset {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 2.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
    background: #e3d5ba;
}

#deliveryinfo label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

#deliveryinfo input {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 130px;
}

#fnameinputacct, #lnameinputacct, #phoneinputacct, #accountidbox {
    width: 12em;
}

#submitBtn {
    font-size: 1.25em;
}
```

And some Javascript that goes with the fields. This method is added in another function.

```
            function createID() {
            var fname = document.getElementById("fnameinputacct");
            var lname = document.getElementById("lnameinputacct");
            var phone = document.getElementById("phoneinputacct");
            var account = document.getElementById("accountidbox");
            var fields = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            var acctid;
            var fistInit;
            var lastInit;

            if (fname != "" && lname != "" && phone != "") {
                fistInit = fname.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
                lastInit = lname.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
                acctid = fistInit + lastInit + phone.value.substring(phone.value.length - 4);
                account.value = acctid;
                newAccountArray = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < fields.length - 1; i++) {
                    newAccountArray.push(fields[i].value);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try breaking up your form field groups with a `<div>` or `<p>`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/How_to_structure_an_HTML_form

Some of the widely used css frameworks do this as well.  Look at Semantic UI, Bootstrap, or Material.  These do a similar grouping with `div` containers for each `label`/`input`

Example from [semantic ui form](https://semantic-ui.com/collections/form.html):

```
<form class="ui form">
  <div class="field">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="first-name" placeholder="First Name">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="last-name" placeholder="Last Name">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <div class="ui checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" tabindex="0" class="hidden">
      <label>I agree to the Terms and Conditions</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="ui button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```